# How to open different url's one after another in one tab?

Tags: vbscript

I have the following problem:

How to open different one after another (after five minutes) in **one** tab using VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

Simply navigate to the URLs one after the other in a loop:

```
list = Array("http://www.example.com", ...)

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

For Each url In list
  ie.Navigate url
  While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Wend
  WScript.Sleep 300000  'wait 5 min before loading the next page
Next
```

Add an outer loop of you want to start over after the last URL.